# New kafka pod replicas cannot find CA on scaling

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a kubernetes cluster with a kafka zookeeper statefulset that works fine with one pod. However, when for performance reasons I try to scale the statefulset to three pods with the following command:

```
kubectl scale statefulset <my_zookeper_statefulset> --replicas=3
```

The two new pods go into an Error and then a CrashLoopBackOff with the following logs:

```
Detected Zookeeper ID 3
Preparing truststore
Adding /opt/kafka/cluster-ca-certs/ca.crt to truststore /tmp/zookeeper/cluster.truststore.p12 with alias ca
Certificate was added to keystore
Preparing truststore is complete
Looking for the right CA
No CA found. Thus exiting.
```

The certificate in question exists and is used by the existing pod without problem.
The same error occurs when I try to scale my kafka brokers.

Tl;dr: How do I scale kafka up without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you use Kafka you can't go to this way. To do this, you need to configure replicas parameter in your file.
Example of `spec` properties for the `Kafka` resource:

```
apiVersion: YourVersion
kind: Kafka 
metadata: 
  name: my-cluster
spec: 
  kafka: 
    replicas: 3
```

Secondly also you can create [ReplicationController Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) for comfortable work with replicas.